# How can I change the Procfile to run the Gunicorn process in a non-standard folder on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

This is my folder structure:

```
george-paintings
   |
    application
      |
      george_paintings
       |
       george_paintings
        | - wsgi.py
- Procfile
```

In procfile i specify wsgi like

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings george_paintings.wsgi
```

And i got erorr while deploying my project to Heroku

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'george_paintings'
```

T tried different combinations of path in procfile and none of then worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings george_paintings.wsgi
```

to

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi
```

You had a blank space in between the folder names.